# What could cause the ResetEvent API to fail?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a VC++ application.  Just for the sake of argument, what could cause the `ResetEvent` API to fail?  The Microsoft documentation is not clear on this.  Thanks.

Comment: An invalid handle? What does GetLastError say?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would say that the documentation is clear on this. It states that you should pass a handle to an event object, and that object has sufficient access rights. Once you do that I think it has to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commonly an invalid handle will cause this to fail.  An invalid handle, in turn, could result from:

1. the handle being closed by another process or thread prematurely
2. passing gobbledy-gook to ResetEvent()
3. Passing a handle to a thing that isn't an even

Number 1 can often be avoided by creating a duplicate of the handle, by calling [DuplicateHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

GetLastError() generally will tell you exactly what the problem is, or at least point you in the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Without access to the source of Windows we can only guess. Here's my guess at what could go wrong:

- The handle is not a valid handle to an event object.
- The handle does not have the necessary access rights. The documentation states that the handle must have the EVENT_MODIFY_STATE access right.
- The OS runs out of memory or has some other critical failure.

Reading the WINE source reveals no other explicit failure modes.